# mmap flag ‘MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE’ undeclared even with a supported kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mmap

I'm trying to build an application which uses the `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` mmap flag. From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), it seems that the flag is supported since linux kernel 4.17. I currently have `5.4.0-53-generic` installed on my Ubuntu 18.04.5 system. When I try to build the application, I get the following error:

```
cc -MD -c -o ../nondebug/libpmemblk/set.o -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -Wunused-macros -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wfloat-equal -Wswitch-default -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -std=gnu99 -fno-common -pthread -DSRCVERSION=\"1.6+git703.g8cb972fe3\" -DSDS_ENABLED     -I../include -I../common/  -fPIC  ../../src/../src/common/set.c
../../src/../src/common/set.c: In function ‘util_replica_map_local_addr’:
../../src/../src/common/set.c:2661:13: error: ‘MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘_IOS_NOREPLACE’?
     flags | MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE, 0) != 0) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             _IOS_NOREPLACE
../../src/../src/common/set.c:2661:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../Makefile.inc:328: recipe for target '../nondebug/libpmemblk/set.o' failed
```

I checked, and the file `set.c` does include `sys/mman.h` header required for `mmap`. I'm not sure why the compiler is complaining about `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`, and how to fix this.

Comment: Try `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the very top of your file, or `-D_GNU_SOURCE` on the command line.  The man page doesn't list `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` as one of the flags that requires this, but in my system headers, it's controlled by the same ifdefs as those that do.  I guess it's a documentation bug.

Comment: @NateEldredge `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is already there at the top of the file.

Comment: You could try to trace the chain of includes from `<sys/mman.h>` to find the file that actually defines the macro.  For me on Ubuntu 20.04 with glibc 2.31, it's in `/usr/include/bits/mman-map-flags-generic.h`.

Comment: You could bodge it by `#include <sys/mman.h>` `#ifndef MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` `#define MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE 0x100000` `#endif`.

Comment: The `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` support was added in GNU C Library (glibc) version 2.29, so should be defined in Ubuntu's "libc6-dev" package version 2.29 onwards.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Aha, and Ubuntu 18.04 uses [glibc 2.27](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/glibc).  So that explains why it's not there.

Comment: Thanks guys! I upgraded the OS to 20.04 and was able to build the application without any issues.